# Javascript Assign New Field to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

I have a snippet of code here running in a node application

```
for( i=0; i < Equipment.length; i += 1 ) {
    Equipment[i].NumberForSearch = Equipment[i].ClassPrefix + "-" + Equipment[i].UnitNumber;
    console.log(Equipment[i].NumberForSearch);
}

console.log(Equipment[0]);
```

Equipment is an array of objects and I am trying to add a property to each object in that array called "NumberForSearch".

In my application the way we want to display unit numbers for equipment is "ClasssPrefix"-"UnitNumber". The reason I am wanting to join them here into one variable is that inside my angular application, I want the user to be able to type 12345-12345 inside of a search field which then filters out the Equipment. This doesnt work if I have {{ClassPrefix}}-{{UnitNumber}} for obvious reasons, angular doesnt know that the - even exists.

The problem is that inside my for loop everything is checking out fine. Its logging just as its supposed to, so I figured it worked. When I checked the front end and changed it to display "NumberForSearch", nothing showed up.

I then added the logging statement outside the for loop to check just one of my objects to see if the field even existed and it doesnt. So my question is, why is this snippet not adding the "NumberForSearch" field in my object?

Comment: There's nothing in here related to JSON. You're just trying to bind the `NumberForSearch` property to your UI via Angular, correct? Where's that code?

Comment: To clarify: there's no such thing as a JSON object in JavaScript; they're JavaScript objects. JSON is a data exchange format.

Comment: I'm sorry for the miscommunication, I have no problem bringing in my Equipment array into Angular. Im currently displaying all the other fields of Equipment in my application. My issue is that the field "NumberForSearch" does not exist. Therefore leading me to believe that the snippet I posted above is not adding the "NumberForSearch" field

Comment: ` { _id: 55bf8c7782c85cafe90de0a4,
    UnitClassification: 'BAC',
    ClassPrefix: 301,
    UnitNumber: '326',
    Year: 1999,
    Make: 'Komatsu',
    Description: 'Excavator SOLD TO A. SONGSTER              Coupler HAS BUCKET U#331 INSTALLED ON IT.',
    URL: 'HeavyEquipment',
    Active: true,
    Details: 
     { Owner: 'BLM',
       Model: 'PC200LC-6',
       SoldDate: Thu Nov 04 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (MDT) } }`                                                                                                                      This is from console.log(Equimpent[0]);

Comment: @JoshBrown: You're likely attempting to add the field *after* the list has already been bound. The code you have *will* modify the `Equipment` array, I just don't know enough about Angular (and there isn't enough code in your post) to say whether it's the same array bound to the UI, or what the timeline of events that have occurred is. I'd highly recommend providing a [mcve] that we can run.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Thank you for verifying that the above snippet does indeed work and giving me a direction as to what is possibly wrong. I will look more into the timing of my code. If you put an answer down as timing issue I will gladly accept. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make object with this field before setting to $scope's parameter.
Have a look at **init()** function.
After adding **NumberForSearch** field we defined array of objects to parameter in scope.
Of course ng-repeat will loop through it and render elements.
So we will add "**| filter:query**" to show only needed

```
<div ng-controller="EquipmentController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query.NumberForSearch" placeholder="search">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Item in Equipment | filter:query">{{Item.ClassPrefix}}-{{Item.UnitNumber}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js part:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('EquipmentController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $filter) {
      $scope.Equipment = [];
      $scope.init = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/path/to/equipment/resource'
        });

        request.success(function (response) {
            var Equipment = response.Equipment;
            for(var i in Equipment) {
              Equipment[i].NumberForSearch = Equipment[i].ClassPrefix + "-" + Equipment[i].UnitNumber;
            }
            $scope.Equipment = Equipment;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
      }

      $scope.init();
});
```

another way of filtering is to send search field to route, in another word we send query to server and it filters response on serverside.

```
<div ng-controller="EquipmentController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="queryNumber" ng-change="searchByNumber()" placeholder="search">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="Item in Equipment">{{Item.ClassPrefix}}-{{Item.UnitNumber}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

js part:

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.controller('EquipmentController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $filter) {
      $scope.Equipment = [];

      $scope.all = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/path/to/equipment/resource'
        });

        request.success(function (response) {
            $scope.Equipment = response.Equipment;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
      }

      $scope.all();

      $scope.searchByNumber = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/path/to/equipment/resource?number='+$scope.queryNumber
        });

        request.success(function (response) {
            $scope.Equipment = response.Equipment;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
      }
});
```

Comment: just decided to modify Equipment in Angular rather than on the Node side. Thanks.